# Moran process variance (discrete-time)

Tags: stochastic-processes, variance

I'm trying to figure out how to do deviation of the variance in the Moran model:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moran_process.
The one thing that I don't understand is how do you get from 
$$E\left[\left(\frac{2Z}{N}\right)\left(1-\frac{Z}{N}\right)\right]+Var(Z)$$
to $$\left(\frac{2E[Z]}{N}\right)\left(1-\frac{E[Z]}{N}\right)+\left(1-\frac{2}{N^2}\right)Var(Z)$$
Where does $\left(1-\frac{2}{N^2}\right)$ come from?

I'd appreciate your help and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the relation $Var(Z) = E[Z^2] - (E[Z])^2$ as follows

\begin{aligned}
E\left[\left(\frac{2Z}{N}\right)\left(1-\frac{Z}{N}\right)\right]+Var(Z)\quad & = E\left[\frac{2Z}{N}-\frac{2Z^2}{N^2}\right]+Var(Z)\\
&=
\frac{2E[Z]}{N}-\frac{2E[Z^2]}{N^2}+Var(Z)\\
{\small\{\text{use $ E[Z^2] = Var(Z) + (E[Z])^2$ }\}}\qquad&=
\frac{2E[Z]}{N}-\frac{2(Var(Z)+ (E[Z])^2}{N^2}+Var(Z)\\
& = \left(\frac{2E[Z]}{N}\right)\left(1-\frac{E[Z]}{N}\right)+\left(1-\frac{2}{N^2}\right)Var(Z)
\end{aligned}

Comment: Now, I understand where this term comes from. Thank you so much!

Comment: Unfortunately, I have less than 15 reputation points so I cannot up vote your answer. :(